# Unity2D: Rotate object keeping looking at front

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I am trying to archive without success a z-axis rotation movement **around a moving object** keeping always "looking at front". So it should looks like this:
[image]

The closest I got was with:

transform.RotateAround(targetPosition, Vector3.forward, moveSpeed);

But it does not keeps looking "at front".

[image]

Could someone give me a hand with this?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object ("Lightning Bolt") has no world rotation, i.e. aligned with the world axis as your example image seems to suggest, then the easiest is to simply set the world rotation to the Quaternion Identity:

```
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

Note that the image wont rotate if its parent object rotates. It will essentially "Billboard" your lightning object. If you want to your lightning bolt to be aligned with a parent object, then try something like:

```
    transform.rotation = transform.parent.rotation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fitst store the current rotation, then rotate around point, lastly apply the previous rotation.

```
var rot = transform.rotation;
transform.RotateAround(targetPosition, Vector3.forward, moveSpeed);
transform.rotation = rot;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would just manipulate actual coordinates and ignore rotation ^^ If an object moves and you want it to keep rotating around it, just make it a child object.

This is a 3d solution where we rotate around Y:

```
  void Start() { angle = 0.0f }

  void Update() {
       angle += speed * Time.deltaTime; //Your starting angle that will be modified every frame
       CheckAngle(ref angle);

       float x = Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * Radius;
       float z = Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * Radius;
    }

    static void CheckAngle(ref float Angle) //It should probably return a value by it's name here tho not ref, not sure which is the correct way of doing this
    {
       if (Angle > 360) //You don't want your angle to go past the boundaries of an INT
           Angle = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, this solucion does not match with my implementation, but thanks for the so detailed reply =)